# Is there a better way to write this AJAX script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I wanted to create a basic interaction which does 1 outcome but with 2 possible actions: get a number from an other document, by either clicking on a button or waiting a fixed amount of time.

I wrote this, which works:

```
//Initialize the ajax function
(function($) {
    $.fn.getNumber = function() {
        $(this).load('number.html .giver');
    };
})(jQuery);

//Launch ajax function 3s after DOM is loaded
$(function() {
    $('.receiver').delay(3000).queue(function(nxt) {
        $(this).getNumber();
    });
});

//Launch ajax function if a button is clicked
$('button').click(function() {
    $('.receiver').getNumber();
});
```

Now even if it works I'm pretty sure my code is badly written, for instance my `getNumber` function seem redundant. I just fear I might get bad habits, any insights of how I could write this in a more elegant way?

Comment: With working code, consider posting to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - it's more focused on this type of question.

Comment: thanks I didn't know that community

Comment: This is so few code – it's hard to optimize here…